# how to instruct ecto to not create the auto increment id field?

Tags: elixir

Ecto migrations automatically create an auto increment field by name 'id' in the table.

1. How to avoid creating this field?
2. How to set another column in the table as primary key (not auto increment)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can opt out of the automatically generated primary key column with the `primary_key: false` option to `table/2`. You can set another column as primary key with the `primary_key: true` option to `add/3`:

```
create table(:users, primary_key: false) do
  add :my_id, :integer, primary_key: true
  add :name, :string
  # ...
end
```

For more info, please refer to the documentation:

http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/0.11.3/Ecto.Migration.html#table/2
http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/0.11.3/Ecto.Migration.html#add/3